# Redirect Print statment output to file if any command line argument is provided

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, argv

I have written function, it has only functionality to get the details from Openstack using Openstack API. I am already doing logging, however for quick verification of few networks I am redirecting output of couple of print statement to a file. ( it looks like this ), and this works fine.

```
def get_net_details():
    ...
    filename = open('validation.txt', 'a')
    network_name = network['name']
    print >> filename, 'Network Name : {0}'.format(network_name)
    network_id = subnet_detail['subnet']['network_id']
    print >> filename, 'Network ID : {0}'.format(network_id)
    network_type = network['provider:network_type']
    print >> filename, 'Network Type : {0}'.format(network_type)
    print >> "========================================="
    filename.close()
```

Problem is, I want to log the output of print statement to the file only if  user provide any command line input (any switch via argparse or any other way) at the time of script execution.

any help will be appreciated ..!

Comment: Check length of sys.argv and if the input is provided, do your redirection.

Comment: You may try getopt module too, which has standard way of handling command line arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First rewrite your function so that it takes a stream as input:

```
def get_net_details(outstream):
    ...
    network_name = network['name']
    print >> outstream, 'Network Name : {0}'.format(network_name)
    network_id = subnet_detail['subnet']['network_id']
    print >> outstream, 'Network ID : {0}'.format(network_id)
    network_type = network['provider:network_type']
    print >> outstream, 'Network Type : {0}'.format(network_type)
    print >> outream, "========================================="
```

Then let the caller pass either an opened file or `sys.stdout` - depending on the commandline flags - as param.

```
def main(...):
    # argparse stuff here

    if someflag:
        outstream = open(path/to/file, "w")
    else:
        outstream = sys.stdout
    try:
        get_net_details(outstream)
    finally:
        if someflag:
            outstream.close()
```